# Rails 4: how do I generate an error message in login view?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, session, ruby-on-rails-4, authentication, notice

Here in the login view I have this code:

```
<p id="notice"><%= notice %></p>

<h1>Log In</h1>

<%= form_tag({controller: "sessions", action: "create"}) do %>
<% if false %>
<% if errors.any? %>
  <div id="error_explanation">
    <h2><%= pluralize(errors.count, "error") %> unseccessful:</h2>

    <ul>
    <% errors.full_messages.each do |message| %>
      <li><%= message %></li>
    <% end %>
    </ul>
  </div>
<% end %>
<% end %>

  <div class="field">
    <%= label_tag :username %><br/>
    <%= text_field_tag :username, params[:username] %><br/>
  </div>
  <div class="field">
    <%= label_tag :password %><br/>
    <%= password_field_tag :password %><br/>
  </div>
  <div class="actions">
    <%= submit_tag "Log In" %>
  </div>

<% end %>
```

and if I enter incorrect user information it should give some notice from the controller:

```
def create

    user = User.find_by_username(params[:username])
    respond_to do |format|
      if user && user.password == params[:password]
        session[:user_id] = user.id
        format.html { redirect_to root_url, notice: 'Logged In successfully' }
        format.json { render :index, status: :created, location: @session }
      else

        format.html { render :new, notice: "Email or password is invalid" }
        format.json { render json: @session.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
        #flash.now.alert = "Email or password is invalid"
        #render "new"
      end
    end
  end
```

but instead it just reloads the login page with no notice or error message whatsoever. I'm new to Rails, do you have any idea what I can do?

Answer (score 1):

In your code there are various issues:

1. You have mentioned `<% if false %>` may be you were debugging the code, remove that.
2. In your controller you have not made instance variable, it is local variable. `user` should be `@user`.
3. On the view instead of using `errors` it should be `@user.errors` as it will never get the local variable `errors` because it is not defined.
4. In the `format.json` you have mentioned `@session` and `@session.errors`, I don't remember if any variable of this name exists, it will return `nil` may be.
5. I believe using `form_for` instead of `form_tag` for these forms is good practice and you will never need to mention `controller` and `action`, Rails will do that automatically.
6. In `create` action you are finding the `user` instead of creating it which is completely wrong.

And I think after these things also you may face more issues so please read the tutorial carefully.

Comment: Yes, I now have "undefined method `errors' for nil:NilClass" error(I changed user to @user and tried to call @user.errors.any? where it caused an error to occur. Any idea what I can do about that?

You are right about tutorials, I need to complete this project asap though. Learning while doing :)

Comment: It is hard to help like this because your code has a large number of issues and you have not read the tutorials properly. Still I have pointed out many issues to you. So please go through the tutorial carefully.

Comment: I don't really understand if I should create a form_for @ user or @ session? When I try to create a @session = Sessions.new in controller it gives an error too. And what tutorial are you referring to?

Comment: You can refer this tutorial which will give you an idea: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/getting_started.html